# SublimeLinter pep8_ignore not working

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pep8

I want SublimeLinter to ignore PEP-8 E402 error messages.  I have changed the package user settings to

```
"pep8_ignore": [
"E402"
]
```

and have closed and reopened Sublime Text.  SublimeLinter still displays an E402 error code.  Why?

I am using ST3 with these packages: BufferScrool, LaTeXing, PackageControl, PackageResourceViewer, R-Box, Side Bar, Anaconda, and SublimeLinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, I'd note that [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/) performs its own version of PEP-8 linting, so you've got some functional duplication happening...

Second, I'd note that you don't seem to have [SublimeLinter-pep8](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pep8) installed, which means (since SublimeLinter installed by Package Control on ST3 is going to be SublimeLinter3, which requires linting plugins to do anything) that its not SublimeLinter. Things to consider: (1) are the linting errors you see coming from Anaconda rather than SublimeLinter? If so you need to set `"pep8_ignore"` in the Anaconda user settings rather than SublimeLinter. (2) Are you (somehow) using the old, unsupported version of SublimeLinter on ST3? In that case, either (a) switch to using Anaconda and ignore SublimeLinter for the purposes of linting python files or (b) upgrade SublimeLinter to SublimeLinter3, install SublimeLinter-pep8 and see below.

Assuming you are actually trying to use the [SublimeLinter-pep8 plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pep8) on SublimeLinter3: SublimeLinter3, which uses an [entirely different settings structure](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html) from the previous version of SublimeLinter. As a result, the `"pep8_ignore"` setting is no longer honoured. This is the expected behaviour.

In order to accomplish what you want you need these settings set in the settings file:

```
{
    "user": {
        "linters": {
             "pep8": {
                 "ignore": "E402"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

But have a careful read of the [SublimeLinter settings docs](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html) as there are a lot of different ways to configure your settings, and have a look at the [docs for the pep-8 plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pep8)

Answer (score 2):

As ig0774 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735278/1426065), Anaconda has its own built-in linters (`pylint`, `pep8`, `pep257`, and `pyflakes`), which are producing the error message you'd like to ignore, *not* SublimeLinter. If for some reason you want to shut off linting with Anaconda and perform it with one or more SublimeLinter plugins, you'll need to install and configure those plugins. [Search](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sublimelinter) Package Control for more information.

To configure Anaconda, first open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Anaconda -> Settings-Default`**, then **`Settings-User`** in the same sub-menu. Copy the entire contents of `Default` to `User`, then close `Default`, as you can't edit it anyway. I highly recommend reading through the entire file, as it is well-commented. The setting you are looking for is also called `"pep8_ignore"`, which in the current version of Anaconda is on line 318. This file seems to change rather often, so this position may change over time. Just search for the name.

If you want to turn off Anaconda's linting capabilities completely, set `"anaconda_linting"` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you, these were both great answers!